# Database error, not null violation, estou passando todos os valores, onde estou errando?

Tags: cakephp

Após preencher o formulário e enviar, retorna o seguinte `array`:

```
array(
       'User' => array(
               'password' => '*****',
               'nome' => 'Engenharia',
               'username' => 'eng@gmail.com',
               'confirm_password' => '123',
       ),
       'Endereco' => array(
               (int) 0 => array(
                    'cidade_id' => '3091',
                          'cep' => '96032012',
                          'rua' => 'Conde de porto alegre',
                          'numero' => '420',
                          'bairro' => 'Porto',
                          'complemento' => 'Empresa'
                  )
        ),
        'UserGroup' => array(
                 'group_id' => '2',
                 'nome' => 'Cliente'
         )
)
```

Logo em seguida, recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> **Database Error**
>   Error: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "nome" violates not-null constraint. DETAIL: Failing row contains (87, 2, 180, null).
>   Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/pdo_error.ctp

Mas não entendi de onde ele está tirando esse `nome == null`, pois estou passando o nome do `User` e estou passando o nome do `UserGroup` também, onde posso estar errando?

Comment: Parece que o erro não é aqui. Alguma coisa a mais pode esta ocorrendo e causando o erro.

Comment: Pois é, já verifiquei bastante, mas não estou encontrando o problema :|

Comment: Estou salvando com `$this->User->saveAssociated($this->request->data);`

Comment: É possível você retirar essa constraint do banco temporariamente para ver o que será gravado? Talvez vendo o que foi gravado você descubra onde esta o erro.

Comment: Verdade, vou dar uma olhada!

Comment: Tirei a constraint do campo `nome` da tabela `UserGroup` e salvou normalmente, mas com valor null é claro.
Será que tem conflito com o as duas tabelas com campos de mesmo nome ?
`User => 'nome'` e a `UserGroup => 'nome'`

Comment: Esse array é exatamente antes do save? Referente a conflito com nome de duas tabelas iguais, vai depender do seu Model...

Comment: Sim ele é antes do save, não sei o que aconteceu, mas resolvi remover este campo da tabela do banco e utilizar o de outra tabela que fazia a mesma função.
Só fiz mais um relacionamento na tabela e busquei os valores dessa nova tabela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Minha solução:**

Após preencher o formulário e enviar, retorna o seguinte `array`:

```
array(
       'User' => array(
               'password' => '*****',
               'nome' => 'Engenharia',
               'username' => 'eng@gmail.com',
               'confirm_password' => '123',
       ),
       'Endereco' => array(
               (int) 0 => array(
                    'cidade_id' => '3091',
                          'cep' => '96032012',
                          'rua' => 'Conde de porto alegre',
                          'numero' => '420',
                          'bairro' => 'Porto',
                          'complemento' => 'Empresa'
                  )
        ),
        'UserGroup' => array(
                 'group_id' => '2',
         )
)
```

> Removi o campo `nome` da tabela `UserGroup` que estava em conflito e utilizei o `nome` (que eu precisava) de outra tabela já existente no banco, então fiz somente um relacionamento no `Controller` para chamar essa tabela e funcionou perfeitamente!!